# How to resize numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have NumPy array x_train, and it has shape (880,):

```
x_train.shape
(880,)
```

Every element of this array is image with shape (256, 192, 3)

```
x_train[0].shape
(256, 192, 3)
```

How to reshape x_train array to get array of size (880, 256, 192, 3)

Comment: How did you create `x_train` in the first place? It's probably better to create it correctly the first time than try alter it later.

Comment: try `np.stack[(x_train)`

Comment: thx, it works .